# Novel where the protagonist knows he will have his memory about a magical world erased and write everything down beforehand

Tags: story-identification, novel

I recently remembered a story I read when I was younger about a boy discovering a magical world (maybe even situated in our own) but his memory gets erased because humans are not allowed to know about it. Knowing this, he writes everything down before and then rediscover his notes and remember (or rediscover) the magic. In my memory the magic is about magical creatures, like fairies, not wizards a la Harry Potter.

As I read this quite some time ago, the memory are very fuzzy, and it is totally possible I am mixing up multiple stories in one, but I am pretty sure about the memory thing.

I think the novel was intented for children or maybe young teenagers. I read it in my native tongue (French), and I don't know if it was translated or not.

Comment: How much younger? Are we looking for something in the current century? This [page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) might be useful to help recall any other details that can help us.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is ***Artemis Fowl* by Eoin Colfer**.

After discovering the world of the fairies - and kidnapping one - the titular character, Artemis, gets his memories erased. However, he manages to hide certain information on a disk, and leaves himself enough notes that he eventually remembers everything.

It's an urban fantasy setting, mostly; the world of fairies is hidden from the modern world.

> In The Eternity Code, Artemis Fowl II and Butler experienced a fine-tune wipe due to their extensive knowledge of fairies and great time spent with them. However, Artemis (and Butler) managed to promote total recall by creating a disk of all their fairy knowledge and adventures before the mind-wipe and then disguising and entrusting the disk in Mulch Diggums's care.
> <sub>[Fandom](https://artemisfowl.fandom.com/wiki/Mind-wipe)</sub>

---

Identified by recognizing the description.

Comment: Yes thank you it is precisely it! It has been bugging me the past few days to know be able to remember it, but I will know be able to read it again.